# How to show keyboard hits while recording with kazam?

Tags: keyboard, screenshot, recording

Looking to make some demonstrations or tutorials, I am able to record the screen "easily" with kazam. However, even if the mouse pointer is recorded, keyboard shortcuts are not. 
For some software, keyboard shortcuts are extremely important and nearly impossible to reproduce with the mouse.

I installed `florence` and `onboard` hopping it would show my keyboard hits, but that is not the case.

I am looking for a software that can run on Debian and which can show any keys which are pressed on screen, so I can record them in the video.

Note: For Linux Debian 10-buster.

Comment: you may want to look into screenkey...